# How to tell socket.io to immediately reconnect when navigator.online changes to true

Tags: socket.io, navigator

We set the `reconnectionDelayMax` ([docs-ref](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#new-Manager-url-options)) to max. 10 seconds.

So when a user is offline for a while `socket.io` will retry only every 10 seconds - which is good, but it also means, that a user must wait for up to 10 seconds when they get online.
Which is basically also okay, but can be improved in some cases:

We want to listen to the [navigator.ononline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/ononline) event and then "reset" the reconnection logic: i.e. try to reconnect immediately (with the initial `reconnectionDelay`)

Is this possible in `socket.io` (client v2.x)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding something like this that would fire when the browser goes online and (re)connect the socket

```
window.addEventListener('online', function () {
  const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: This will create a new connection and lose all cached events that were emitted since disconnection. We just want tp "force" the "normal " reconnection, so that the cached events are also sent on success.